# How to clear a <label>'s text

Tags: jquery

Trying to figure out how to clear my label's text...clear it out.  So far no luck:

```
$("label[id*=\"singleModelText\"]").text().empty();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
$('label[id*="singleModelText"]').text('');
```

Comment: How is this answer different from mine setting aside his use of the quotation marks? They are not necessary.

Comment: They might not be all the time, but they are the standard.

Answer (score 6):

Or if .text('') doesn't work

```
$('label[id*=singleModelText]').html('');
```

but if there's an id why not just do this:

```
$('#singleModelText').html('');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
   $('label[id*=singleModelText]').empty();
```

OR

```
   $('label[id*=singleModelText]').text('');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('label[id*="singleModelText"]').text('')
```

Keep in mind that there is a simpler id selector of `$('#ID')` assuming you have the full id and not just a partial id

Here is a JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QFseE/

Comment: Quotation marks around the attribute value (`singleModelText`) are required.

Comment: @andrew respectfully, no they aren't. It will work fine without them. I omit them all the time. You can also review the js fiddle or test it yourself.'

Comment: Please read the documentation for this selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/. **"value: An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory."**. Even though they work in this particular case, I would say following jQuery's documentation is probably a smart idea `:)`. I've had serious issues omitting them before.

Comment: @Matthew: you're right that it works, but Andrew's recommendation for following the documentation is a good one.  If newer versions of jQuery decide to enforce the quotes in a strict manner, you will not have to go back and update your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('label[id*="singleModelText"]').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#singleModelText').contents().first().replaceWith('');